# Jenkins hangs after "chroot . sh" during ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh, chroot

I'm doing a Jenkins freestyle build, ssh'ing into a VM and running some existing scripts.  During a build step "Execute shell script on remote host using ssh", everything is working fine until I get to a command:  "chroot . sh".  This is mounting a rootfs which we build in, if I do this step manually it is bringing me to a sh prompt where I can run another script to do the actual build, but Jenkins just hangs forever at this point.

From looking around it looks like this is because the command does not return a completion signal?, so Jenkins is waiting indefinitely.  I've also just tried doing the same steps in Putty, using a text file containing the commands I need.  The Putty "script" also fails at this point, stopping any input because of the new sh prompt.

Is there any way around this?  I've tried various solutions, like:
nohup chroot . sh 1>&2   - of course this doesnt work
and running the command in the background doesnt put me into the chroot environment I need.

Kind of confused at this point.

Edit:
Code snippet:

```
cd /home/dev/root_env
chroot . sh
cd /home/dev
./build.sh
```

Thats literally all I'm doing, however I freeze forever at line 2 of that.

Comment: Will be nice to see problematic code example

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited the question with snippet.